# Invalid identifier while compiling stored procedure pl sql

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, oracle11g

This is a small test code I have written.

```
CREATE procedure abc
IS
  tempHistoricalClassAvg integer;
begin
  select avg(e.obtainedquizscore)
  into   tempHistoricalClassAvg
  ,      e.courseid
  from   evaluation e 
  where  e.courseid = 1 
  and    e.instructorid =1 
  group by e.courseid;

  dbms_output.Put_line(tempHistoricalClassAvg);
end;
```

I get a compiler error saying

```
Error(5,62): PLS-00201: identifier 'E.COURSEID' must be declared
```

E.courseid is present in the table as the below query works fine

```
select avg(obtainedquizscore) as avgquizscore
,      courseid  
from   evaluation 
where  courseid  = 1 
and    instructorid =1 
group by courseid;
```

Where am I wrong? :/

Comment: I don't think you can have a column name after the `INTO <your variable>` clause.

Comment: Remove the `e.courseid` from the `into` clause.